# Double integration in a region extending below the x-axis

Tags: integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals

For area under a curve, we separately calculated areas above vs below the x-axis, taking the absolute value for the latter to add to the former.

I'm not sure how this translates to the double integration case. First of all, sorry for asking something can be done by trial but the question I'm working on does not have worked solutions so since I can't get the exact final answer I'm spending hours working blindly.

I have a triangle bounded by $y_1 -1 \leq y_2\leq -y_1+1$ and $0 \leq y_1 \leq 1$. This is where the equation to integrate is $f(y_1, y_2) = 6y_1^2 y_2$ is defined. I'm asked to integrate doubly over $y_1 < \frac{1}{2}, y_2 < \frac{1}{2}$ (this is a probability question where the equation is a pdf and the ask is to find the joint probability of $y_1 < \frac{1}{2}, y_2 < \frac{1}{2}$).

I am guessing the need to take absolute values is different and more complex because although the "area" below x-axis is negative, the z-level is not necessarily negative. Therefore I'm not quite sure how it works.

I've attempted an all-at-once approach which I didn't expect to work and it didn't e.g.
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \int_{y_1 -1}^{1/2} 30y_1^2 y_2 dy_2 dy_1 
$$
I've also tried separately doing the parts above and below the x-axis:
$$
\int_{0}^{1/2} \int_{0}^{1/2} 30y_1^2 y_2 dy_2 dy_1 + \int_{0}^{1/2} \int_{y_1 -1}^{0} 30y_1^2 y_2 dy_2 dy_1
$$
But it doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps my algebra is wrong but again with no worked solutions and so far having not found any errors, I have no idea what's going on.

PS the answer is 9/16

Comment: Are the bounds of the triangle correct? Because in that case $y_2$ could be negative which cannot be true if $f$ is a pdf.

Comment: The fact that it is a triangle was deduced by me, but the inequality given was copied directly from the book. Are you saying it may be meant that $0 \leq y_2 \leq 1$ or at least $0 \leq y_2 $ and the book has an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!!

My method of 
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \int_{y_1 -1}^{1/2} 30y_1^2 y_2 dy_2 dy_1 
$$
was supposed to work, I must have made an algebraic error. 
Would like to hear an explanation about how $y_2$ cannot be negative though, since I still don't really understand how I got the right answer and what it would mean conceptually.